# create a library in JavaScript and include it in my project in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a small JavaScript file with some function I would like to be able to call them in an angular project, I searched for guides but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Services, I assume you're using Angular 2+ so here's the guide for that:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

In case you're still using AngularJS here's the guide for the old version:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

In both cases the concept is simple, you have your service(s) with the functionality you need across the app and you inject them where you need to use them.